# How to show a ListFragment on top right screen when user click a button

Tags: android

I want to show a ListFragment when user click a button on the top right corner.
When user select a item in this ListFragment or just touch the screen outside the ListFragment, the ListFragment should be disappeared.

Just like below

[screen shot image](http://blog.chengbo.net/wp-content/uploads/listview.png)
(i don't have rights to post an image, so I have uploaded it to my blog)

I tried to use DialogFragment to wrap the ListFragment, but I find no way to set the dialog's position, it always shows in the center, I need to display the ListFragment on the top right of screen.

And I also tried to use PopupWindow, but I don't know how to set a ListFragment as popupwindows' contentview.

So, my questions are:

1. how to show a ListFragment when user click a button, this
   ListFragment should be shown at top right corner.
2. how to hide this ListFragment when user select a item of this ListFragment or touch
   the screen outside the ListFragment.

Sorry for my poor English :)

Answer (score 0):

Place all your view in a RelativeLayout and set these attributes to your ListView:

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

Also change the size of your ListView programmatically on any event you like.